# ViewPager и RecyclerView получить текущий list

Tags: java, android

Есть `ViewPager` в котором `RecyclerView` формируется список, используется `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` который сразу формирует несколько фрагментов. Ситуация такая, что при запуске фрагмента формируется `list` для `RecyclerView` на основании этого `list` обрабатываются нажатия на элемент списка. Но проблема в том, что `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` формирует сразу `list` для следующего фрагмента. Вопрос как получить текущий `list`, который отображен на данный момент на экране?

Comment: `viewPager.getCurentItem()`? Попробуйте лучше описать в чём ваша проблема.

Comment: Непонятно, куда именно получить, и почему это проблема? Ссылка на этот list есть у адаптера, который его отображает, ссылка на адаптер есть во фрагменте.

Comment: Когда запускается показ вкладки FragmentStatePagerAdapter формирует сразу два экрана (получается что он прогоняет код два раза) у меня есть метод в котором адаптеру передается список значений и он срабатывает два раза. И получается что даже если я с адаптера тяну список это все равно список для следующей вкладки, но никак не для текущей.

Comment: вот тут описал свою проблему http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621016/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E-viewpager-%D0%B8-recyclerview