# Правильно ли я делаю (ViewPager и RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Просьба помочь с алгоритмом действий. Есть `DrawerLayout` по нажатию на его пункт отрывается фрагмент-1 в котором присутствует `RecyclerView` который выводит список пунктов. По нажатию пункта открывается новый фрагмент-2 в котором  присутствует:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

и в котором адаптеру `ViewPager` передается название вкладок и количество создаваемых фрагментов

```
ViewPagerPhraseAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerPhraseAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    for (int i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
        adapter.addFragment(new PhraseFragmentTabPager(), tabList[i]);
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

соответственно есть и фрагмент-3 (тот который показывает содержимое вкладок)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_phrase_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

в котором адаптеру `RecyclerView` передается сгенерированный в коде фрагмента-3 список `listItems` показа исходя из названия текущей вкладки и в нем же обрабатываются нажатия на элементы списка.

Правильно ли генерировать список `listItems` в фрагменте-3 и обрабатывать нажатия в нем же?

В ответ на первый комментарий:
Дело в том, что мой алгоритм обработки нажатий на элементы `RecyclerView` базируется на использовании списка показа `listItems`, который генерируется в фрагменте-3, я получаю при нажатии на элемент его `position` в текущем отображении, потом вытягиваю из базы значения для обработки:

```
recyclerPhraseAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerPhraseAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position, View v) {
            PhrasebookDatabase phrase = PhrasebookDatabase.findById(PhrasebookDatabase.class, listItems.get(position).getSequenceNumber()); // это мы получаем
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.starImageView:
                        phrase.setFavourites(false);
                    break;
                case R.id.shareImageView:
                    openShareDialog(position);
                    break;
                case R.id.phraseLinearLayout:
                        phrase.setHistory(true);
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
```

И я получаю для себя проблему, так как я использую `ViewPager` то он генерирует для показа несколько экранов, и получается что на экране я вижу один список, но в использовать его не могу, так как `ViewPager`сгенерировал уже список `listItems`  для следующего экрана. И у меня выходит, что я при нажатии на элемент списка на текущем экране, получаю данные для элемента списка со следующего экрана.
Как то так!.

код из фрагмента-3

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) myView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_phrase_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    generateList();
    recyclerPhraseAdapter = new RecyclerPhraseAdapter(listItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerPhraseAdapter);
```

и сам `generateList();`

```
private void generateList() {      
    List<PhrasebookDatabase> listPhrase = PhrasebookDatabase.find(PhrasebookDatabase.class, "theme = ? and subparagraph = ?", nameTheme, nameTab); // делаем запрос
    for (int i = 0; i < listPhrase.size(); i++) {
        int resId;
        if (!listPhrase.get(i).getFavourites()) {
            resId = R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp;
        } else {
            resId = R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp;
        }
        listItems.add(new RecyclerPhraseItem(listPhrase.get(i).getInRussian(), listPhrase.get(i).getTranscription(), listPhrase.get(i).getInGerman(), resId, listPhrase.get(i).getSequenceNumber()));

    }
}
```

Comment: Что вас смущает в вашем решении, почему вы думаете, что это может быть неправильно?

Comment: я дополнил свой вопрос.

Comment: Кажется ваш вопрос про то когда и как правильно делать что-то во фрагменте при его создании/открытии?

Comment: а объявляете listItems тоже в третьем фрагменте?

Comment: Да, в третьем фрагменте объявляю, наполняю и передаю его адаптеру RecyclerView

Comment: покажите строчку как генерируете, такое ощущение что у Вас во всех listItems хранится ссылка на один список. Попробуйте присваивать так:   listItems.addAll(provideItems()), где provideItems() возвращает нужный лист

Comment: обновил вопрос, код в самом низу

Comment: и при клике на итем вы получаете в listItems.get(position) итем со следующей страницы?

Comment: да, position получаю с текущего вида экрана, а вот данные с listitems берет уже со следующего экрана, так как listitems уже сформирован для следующего экрана

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52847/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб возможно и так, направьте меня, будьте так добры, а то мозг скоро будет взорван)

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, у вас, наверное, данные не фо фрагменте хранятся, а в активити или какой-то статической переменной к-л класса... И ViewPager, создавая фрагменты их запрашивает и переписывает. Вам надо данные для разных фрагментов хранить в разных местах, лучше всего в самих фрагментах - так они друг-друга затирать не будут

Comment: Я правильно понял, что мне в адаптер ViewPager помимо названия вкладки нужно еще и передать то, что ему отображать на этой вкладке, а не формировать эти данные в фрагменте-3?